# Can't return form submit to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So I have a form, and if the input is invalid, I won't let the form pass like so

```
$(".main-form").submit(function(e){
   return false;
});
```

This won't let the form pass. When the user complete everything correctly I try to do this

```
$(".main-form").submit(function(e){
   return true;
});
```

But for some reason it stays `false` all the way though. Any workarounds?

Comment: Please proof-read your posting for spelling and grammar.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a single `submit` handler:

```
$(".main-form").submit() {
    if (...) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

where `...` contains your validation checks. The actual code might be somewhat more complex, e.g.

```
    if (field1 is invalid) {
        return false;
    } else if (field2 is invalid) {
        return false;
    } 
        ...
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Or just `if(!...) return false`. Returning true doesn’t add anything.

Comment: You're missing your ending curly bracket for `else`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the old handler, so you'd initialize it like this:

```
$(".main-form").on('submit', function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Then to change the handler:

```
$(".main-form").off('submit');
$(".main-form").on('submit', function(e){
   return true;
});
```